# change order of keys with shift on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, custom-keyboard

What is my issue:
- right now I'm using keyboard layout Polish - Programmer and when i click a key right to `0 )` i get `-` (minus) and `_` (when with `Shift`)

What I would like to have:
- pressing key next to `0 )` should put `_` and `-` (with `Shift`)

I tried the app Sharp Keys but with that I'm able only to swap the key with other one, not to change the 'shift behavior' for that specific key.

Could any one assist me with that please?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for this was to install [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)
Then to modify selected Keyboard layout and switch these characters.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.